# Fatal error Joomla-PHP | Dominio 1&1

Tags: php, joomla3

Tengo un **dominio contratado** en **1&1** y desde hace unos días entro en la web y me sale este **error**. ¿Sabéis cual puede ser el **origen del problema**?

**Gracias** por vuestra atención.

`Fatal error: Cannot use Joomla\String\String as String because 'String' is a special class name in /homepages/43/d585417661/htdocs/libraries/vendor/joomla/registry/src/Format/Json.php on line 12`

**URL de la web:** http://vectoridiomas.es/

**Código del archivo Json.php:**

```
   <?php
/**
 * Part of the Joomla Framework Registry Package
 *
 * @copyright  Copyright (C) 2005 - 2015 Open Source Matters, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * @license    GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE
 */

namespace Joomla\Registry\Format;

use Joomla\Registry\AbstractRegistryFormat;
use Joomla\String\String;

/**
 * JSON format handler for Registry.
 *
 * @since  1.0
 */
class Json extends AbstractRegistryFormat
{
    /**
     * Converts an object into a JSON formatted string.
     *
     * @param   object  $object   Data source object.
     * @param   array   $options  Options used by the formatter.
     *
     * @return  string  JSON formatted string.
     *
     * @since   1.0
     */
    public function objectToString($object, $options = array())
    {
        return String::unicode_to_utf8(json_encode($object));
    }

    /**
     * Parse a JSON formatted string and convert it into an object.
     *
     * If the string is not in JSON format, this method will attempt to parse it as INI format.
     *
     * @param   string  $data     JSON formatted string to convert.
     * @param   array   $options  Options used by the formatter.
     *
     * @return  object   Data object.
     *
     * @since   1.0
     */
    public function stringToObject($data, array $options = array('processSections' => false))
    {
        $data = trim($data);

        if ((substr($data, 0, 1) != '{') && (substr($data, -1, 1) != '}'))
        {
            $ini = AbstractRegistryFormat::getInstance('Ini');
            $obj = $ini->stringToObject($data, $options);
        }
        else
        {
            $obj = json_decode($data);
        }

        return $obj;
        }
    }
```

**ACTUALIZADO**

Estoy intentado **actualizar** la versión de **Joomla**, de la **3.4.3** a la **3.6.4** y salta el siguiente **error**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido... podrías mostrar el código?

Comment: Al parecer es un error de que se ha resuelto en joomla 3.5 https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues/7571 de todas formas si  lo buscas por google vas a encontrar muchas respuestas

Comment: He actualizado el post... Ahí tenéis el código

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es un error conocido de versiones antiguas de Joomla!, ocurre al utilizar PHP7 con versiones del CMS que no son compatibles con dicha versión de PHP.

Actualmente debería funcionar sin problema si utilizas la versión más reciente, 3.6.4

Más información del bug puedes encontrar en el repositorio GitHub de Joomla!: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues/7571

Comment: Lo único que tampoco me deja entrar en el panel de control de Joomla...

Comment: ¿Puedes cambiar la versión de PHP a 5.4 en 1&1? Normalmente deberías poder.

Comment: Eso iba a intentar, resetear la versión, actualizar joomla y luego el php

Comment: En 1&1 puedes usar las versiones: 5.5, 5.6 y 7.0 - Si quieres usar 5.4 en 1&1 hay costes adicionales por lo visto -  @Antonio

Comment: En ese caso 5.5 debería funcionar sin problema (no conozco 1&1), sugerí 5.4 por ser lo más "antiguo" con lo cual puede funcionar Joomla 3.x, aunque técnicamente lo menos es 5.3.10

Comment: No si, ya se que el error es por la incompatibilidad de la versión de PHP con Joomla. El problema es que estoy intentado actualizar Joomla y me salen errores de log... He mirado en la información del Servidor y pone que no son escribibles... Y tras eso he intentado dar a la carpeta logs permisos 755, pero seguía teniendo acceso denegado... Asi que no se muy bien que hacer ahora...